# Azure Function APIs cannot be found after CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Yet a learner in Azure Functions, experiencing an issue seems strange to me.

I have (manually) published (in debug mode) an Azure Function App with anonymous authentication level, from Visual Studio 2017. This only does a simple CRUD operation using entity framework core. The runtime version of the Azure Function is 2. This was working just fine testing from Postman. And here's just the signature of one of the functions (they all have the same Route but with different HTTP verbs as per CRUD operation)

```
[FunctionName("DeleteProductFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "delete", Route = "product")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

*The problem:*

It all started once I setup a CI/CD pipelines using Azure DevOps. The whole pipeline goes successfully and it publishes the new version into the Azure Function truly. After that, going back to Postman for testing, I am receiving 404 for all of my APIs (CRUD).

*What I've done:*

- I've tried to delete the existing publish profile and create a new one from scratch using Visual Studio 2017.
- Also, have created a new release pipeline for this.
- I looked into the Function from App Service Editor (preview) to see if actually everything is up there
- I tested the app locally and it just works fine

What have I messed up with in here? I have no clue!

Any opinions, experience sharing, or help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run the azure function on the portal once just to make sure it's been deployed , before testing on the postman and see if you get any errors or results ?

Comment: I can't because they all are read-only now and I don't have that green run button anymore. But I trust that it's been deployed as I have seen my changes from the App Editor. I can probably try to get rid of the read-only thing to test the function from the portal.. should Google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I've found the solution. Basically, I've exposed that in my question without noticing that :)

I messed up with the Build definition: I have Build, Archive, and Publish Artifact as the tasks in my Build definition. The first one outputs the published files into a "output_publish" folder. The next task, Archive, by default also is set to this folder for "Root Folder or File to archive". I was having an error that the "specified path cannot be found." To (only) avoid this error, I (carelessly) selected the Main folder of my project instead of the "publish_output". This was problematic! why? because when everything went up to Azure, then, "function.json" was looking for the "dll" as per this path  "scriptFile": "../bin/MyFunctionApp.dll", this path was not valid though.

*How I fixed that?*

In my Build definition, I added the "publish_output" right after my project main folder, that is, "project_folder/publish_output". Then, the above dll path was resolved and my function now is properly working.

Hope this could come helpful for others maybe..